# What does the product of two density matrices represent physically?

Tags: measurement, density-matrix, bloch-sphere

A quantum state, *pure* or *mixed*, can be described by a density matrix that encodes the Bloch vector $\hat{m}$ analog of a quantum state like

$\rho = \frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I} + \hat{m}.\vec{\sigma}]$.

Let $\rho_{\hat{m}_{1}} = \frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I} + \hat{m}_{1}.\vec{\sigma}]$, $\rho_{\hat{m}_{2}} = \frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I} + \hat{m}_{2}.\vec{\sigma}]$ be two different density matrix, each describing a quantum state $| \psi \rangle$ so that $| \psi \rangle = \rho_{\hat{m}_{1}} + \rho_{\hat{m}_{2}}$

What does $\rho_{\hat{m}_{1}} . \rho_{\hat{m}_{2}}$ describe physically?

Also, the probability that a measurement on the state $| \psi \rangle$ along measurement basis $\hat{m}$ with a measurement outcome being $O$ (or $|O \rangle$) can be described mathematically like $P(O_{\hat{m}}) | \psi \rangle = \text{Tr}[\rho_{\hat{m}_{1}} . \rho_{\hat{m}_{2}}] = \frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I} + \hat{m}_{1}.\hat{m}_{2}]$? This is just Born's rule but how do I convince myself of the expression $\text{Tr}[\rho_{\hat{m}_{1}} . \rho_{\hat{m}_{2}}]$ and result $\frac{1}{2}[\mathbb{I} + \hat{m}_{1}.\hat{m}_{2}]$?

Comment: The addition of two density matrices cannot be a valid quantum state.
Tr($|\psi \rangle$) = Tr($\rho_{m_1} +\rho_{m_2} $) = Tr($\rho_{m_1}$) + Tr($\rho_{m_2}$) = 1+1 = 2.

Comment: In one place you have the sum and another you have the product of density matrices. Also, you have a ket being equal to a density matrix. I think you have a few things confused, so if you could please clarify throughout that would help us help you